# How to update navigation bar selected item when I press back?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

The navigation `item` only updates when I press it manually in the `navigation bar` when I press back it navigates back but the highlighted `item` remains the same

```
// navigation bar composable
@Composable
fun BottomBar(navController: NavController) {
    // current destination and bottombar navigation items
    var curDestination by remember { mutableStateOf( 0 )}
    val items = listOf(
        BottomBarItem.Home,
        BottomBarItem.History
    )

    // navigation bar
    NavigationBar {
        items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
            NavigationBarItem(
                selected = curDestination == index,
                onClick = {
                    curDestination = index
                    navController.navigate(item.route)
                          },
                label = { Text(text = item.label) },
                icon = {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(
                            id = if (curDestination == index) item.iconSelected else item.icon),
                        contentDescription = item.label
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should override `onBackKeyPressed` event. I don't know if it exists in your framework but something similar should be there. You can also watch for `onActivityResult` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can register an [OnDestinationChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener) on your navController to receive callbacks whenever the current destination changes. You can then update your `curDestination` to the correct index by checking if the destination matches one of your bottom nav items.